# currying functions in python in a loop

Tags: python, lambda, currying

So here is some code that simplifies what I've been working on:

```
vars = {
    'a':'alice',
    'b':'bob',
}
cnames = ['charlie', 'cindy']

commands = []

for c in cnames:
    kwargs = dict(vars)
    kwargs['c'] = c
    print kwargs
    commands.append(lambda:a_function(**kwargs))

print commands

def a_function(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    print a
    print b
    print c

for c in commands:
    print "run for "+ repr(c)
    c()
```

And here is its output:

```
{'a': 'alice', 'c': 'charlie', 'b': 'bob'}
{'a': 'alice', 'c': 'cindy', 'b': 'bob'}
[<function <lambda> at 0x1001e9a28>, <function <lambda> at 0x1001e9e60>]
run for <function <lambda> at 0x1001e9a28>
alice
bob
cindy
run for <function <lambda> at 0x1001e9e60>
alice
bob
cindy
```

I would expect to get charlie, then cindy, why is cindy being displayed twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function's body isn't ran until the function is called. When you do `lambda: a_function(**kwargs)`, `kwargs` isn't looked up until you actually *call* the function. At that point it's assigned to the last one you made in the loop.

One solution that gets the result you want would be to do `commands.append(lambda kwargs=kwargs: a_function(**kwargs))`

Comment: cool, this works now


    vars = {
        'a':'alice',
        'b':'bob',
    }
    cnames = ['charlie', 'cindy']

    commands = []

    for c in cnames:
        kwargs = dict(vars)
        kwargs['c'] = c
        print kwargs
        commands.append(lambda kwargs=kwargs:a_function(**kwargs))

    print commands

    def a_function(a=None, b=None, c=None):
        print a
        print b
        print c

    for c in commands:
        print "run for "+ repr(c)
        c()

Comment: I actually ended up storing a dict like this:

    {'kw':kwargs, 'cmd':lambda x:func(**x)}

while doing the lambda kw=kwargs:func(**kw) worked for the example I posted, it didn't in my more complicated program I'm working on.

Answer (score 5):

You're encountering a classic binding-time problem, and @Mike's solution is the classic one. A good alternative is to write a higher order function:

```
def makecall(kwargs):
  def callit():
    return a_function(**kwargs)
  return callit
```

and use `commands.append(makecall(kwargs))` in your loop.  Both solutions work on the same principle (by forcing early binding through passage of an argument -- a plain argument in my case, a default value for a named argument in @Mike's); the choice is just a matter of style or elegance (me, while I tolerate `lambda` in super-simple cases, as long as the subtlest complication intervenes I vastly prefer good old `def`;-).

Comment: Indeed, using something like this or using `functools.partial` is probably a nicer solution. `lambda` aside, a keyword argument is a sort of ugly place to store state.